# Excel VBA Referencing Defined Range

Tags: vba, excel

In the Excel worksheet, I defined say range A1:A10 as "definedvar". I'm trying to use the values in this range to drive pivot table filters. I can't figure out how to reference the defined range values I want. I stepped through the code and the code does go through the pivot table items like I want, but the "definedvar" values has nothing in it. What am I doing wrong?

```
    For Each pi In pt1.PivotFields("COLUMN A").PivotItems
    If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(pi.Name, Range("definedvar"), 0)) Then
        pi.Visible = False
    Else
        pi.Visible = True
    End If
    Next pi
```

Comment: how did you define this range?

Comment: try sheet1.range("definedvar") if it's defined at the worksheet level instead of the workbook level

Comment: The range is defined at the workbook level through the name manager (not in VBA)

Comment: How did you test that the range had nothing in it? Did you `debug.print range("definedvar").address`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item("definedvar").RefersToRange`

```
For Each pi In pt1.PivotFields("COLUMN A").PivotItems
If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(pi.Name, ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item("definedvar").RefersToRange.Value, 0)) Then
    pi.Visible = False
Else
    pi.Visible = True
End If
Next pi
```